# How to customize data bind field in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-livedata

I use data bind in Code A, the `android:text` can disaply correct ID such as '10'.

Now I hope the `android:text` display addadtion information such as "The ID is 10", but Code B doesn't work, how can I fix it?

**Code A**

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@{Integer.toString(aHomeViewModel.idWhenInsert)}" />
```

**Code B**

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="'The ID is '+@{Integer.toString(aHomeViewModel.idWhenInsert)}" />
```

Comment: use bindingadapters

Answer (score 1):

Make the String field in the ViewModel

```
val idWhenInsertString = "The ID is ${idWhenInsert}"
```

and use it in xml

```
android:text="@{aHomeViewModel.idWhenInsertString}"
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I do that in XML ?

Comment: I don't think it's possible.